# Generating all subsets with pairing constraints

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I need to generate all k-subsets of an n-set, with the additional  constraint that some pairs of elements have to be selected either together or not at all. To model this constraint, I thought about explicitly pairing those elements as 2-tuples and keeping the others as 1-tuples. 
So for instance, let's assume I need to select all 3-element subsets of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, with the additional constraints that elements 3 and 4 must be selected together. Then my new set is:

```
{(1,), (2,), (3, 4), (5,)}
```

and the function I want to write would need to generate:

```
{1, 2, 5}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}.
```

Is there a simple way to use itertools (or possibly other python modules I might not know) to obtain this result? I do not care about the order in which I receive those subsets.

In case this simplifies things: an element cannot be paired with more than one other element (so (3, 5) for instance could not have appeared as an additional constraint in my example).

Comment: How big does `n` get? Is iterating over all the original combinations too slow?

Comment: @AlexHall: `n` can be quite large because the actual set I'm interested in the set of all permutations. I'm currently iterating over all combinations and discarding the ones that do not satisfy the pairing constraints, but I was hoping that generating only the "right" combinations directly would be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

def faster(pairs, others, k):
    for npairs in range(k // 2 + 1):
        for pairs_comb in combinations(pairs, npairs):
            for others_comb in combinations(others, k - npairs * 2):
                yield chain(others_comb, *pairs_comb)
```

Explanation:

Go through all the possibilities for the number of pairs in the outcome. For example if `k = 5` then there can either be no pairs and 5 unconstrained elements (`others`), or 1 pair and 3 other elements, or 2 pairs and 1 other element. Then all the combinations of pairs and others can be generated independently and combined.

Test:

```
def brute_force(pairs, others, k):
    return [c for c in combinations(chain(others, *pairs), k)
            if all((p1 in c) == (p2 in c) for p1, p2 in pairs)]

def normalise(combs):
    return sorted(map(sorted, combs))

args = ([(3, 4), (1, 2), (6, 7)], [5, 8, 9, 10, 11], 4)
assert normalise(brute_force(*args)) == normalise(faster(*args))

print(normalise(faster(*args)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just tried this on a few examples, and this is **much** faster than what I had to do previously, even factoring it the time it takes to compute the pairs.